# PostgreSQL as buildInput to nix Flake for building a golang project

Tags: postgresql, go, nix, nix-flake

I have made a nix Flake to build a Golang module. It uses a PostgreSQL database. Is it possible to use flake to install PostgreSQL like this using nix flake. The following code runs and builds the Go module.

```
irmago= buidGoModule {
pname = "irma";

version = "0.8.0"
BuiltInputs =[postgresql]

... and so on
```

The flake is building fine, and the Irma executable is working. However, the PostgreSQL instance is not installed. it is possible to install PostgreSQL and create a database through the same nix flake so that the complete process (Build IRMA, install PostgreSQL, create a database in it, and then perform connection test) is done in one command.
However, as a first step, I am trying to install just PostgreSQL which is not happening.

Comment: Nix by itself does not configure services. Its only purpose is to write store paths. It can produce store paths with service _configuration files_ in them, but it is not responsible for starting and managing services. You can choose from a wide range of tools to do this for you in various scenarios, including NixOS, Arion, NixOps, nixosTest, nix-processmgmt and dockerTools+docker.

Comment: So what do you mean by "the complete process"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If these services are set up and/or managed by a script, this script could be executed by `nix run`, right? You could have Flake `app` outputs `startPostgres`, `resetPostgres`, etc. Of course it would be better to use one of the tools you have listed.

Comment: @raghu , check out this example: https://github.com/nix-community/todomvc-nix (working `nix develop` shell: https://github.com/nix-community/todomvc-nix/pull/44)

Comment: Also https://github.com/numtide/devshell, which is built on top of Flakes, and supports background services: https://numtide.github.io/devshell/getting_started.html#adding-background-services

I am looking for more detail about how that works.